# Flex box sticky side menu

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

[image]Hi guy i'm working on a portfolio for my freecodecamp responsive web design project i already made my wireframe as you can see above but im kind of stuck using flexbox to make a sticky side menu i can't get the 100% height for my main-menu secton here is what i wrote

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav,
ul,
#main-menu {}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  background: #DDD;
  width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="main-menu" class="menu">
    <nav>
      <ul class="box">
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <section id="main"></section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `min-height: 100vh;` this will change the height of the element to the height of the available viewport (visible area in the page). check the snippet below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav,
ul,
#main-menu {
min-height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  background: #DDD;
  width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="main-menu" class="menu">
    <nav>
      <ul class="box">
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
        <li class="menu-item"></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <section id="main"></section>
</main>
```